# Error al tratar de realizar retweet usando TwitterAPIExchange.php

Tags: php, twitter-api

Error al tratar de realizar **retweet** usando `TwitterAPIExchange.php`
Trato de ocupar este código:

```
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');


function RT($id){   
    $settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => 'xxxxxx',
    'consumer_key' => 'xxxxxx',
    'consumer_secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
     );

     $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/'.$id.'.json';
     $requestMethod = 'POST';
     $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
     return $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();
}

echo RT("901856631855730689");
?>
```

Este error aparece al momento de ejecutar el código

> {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

Alguna idea de cual es el motivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de un poco de investigación logre encontrar la respuesta:

```
 $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/'.$id_tweet.'.json';
 $postfields=array();
 $requestMethod = 'POST';
 $wp = array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);
 $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
 $string = json_decode($twitter->setPostfields($postfields)
        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest(true,$wp),$assoc = TRUE); 
 return($string['text']);
```

Solo es cuestion de agregarle el

> setPostfields($postfields)

antes de

> buildOauth

Espero le funcione como referencia Gracias